# How to health check the server status and database status of Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, monitoring, database-performance

I need to monitor/healthcheck the server and databases on MongoDB. Also, is there any automated monitoring possible for MongoDB ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please update your question with more information like What kind of monitoring you are looking for?

Comment: https://grafana.com/dashboards/1530

Comment: Asking for recommendations of products is off-topic for Stack Overflow and in fact on many ( if not all ) Stack Exchange sites. Your question also has nothing to do with **programming**, and that is what this site is for. In the future you can get help with "Database Administration" topics on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com), but even there, asking for such recommendations is "off-topic".

Answer (score 0):

Mongo 4.0+ comes with free cloud monitoring:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/free-monitoring/

Other than that, you can use something like [prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus) with percona’s [MongoDB Exporter](https://github.com/percona/mongodb_exporter).